# Buildozer debug apk matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, debugging, apk, buildozer

I am trying to build apk with buildozer. My project use matplotlib.
I got this error:
STDOUT: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pybind11'

Then i try to include pybind11 on requierements of .spec, and got this error:

STDOUT: ImportError: `certifi` is unavailable (No module named 'certifi') so unable to download any of the following: ['http://www.qhull.org/download/qhull-2020-src-8.0.2.tgz'].

I tried to change the version os matplotlib on .spec requieremenets, but not solve...
Anyone can help?
Thanks

Itry to include pybind11 on requierements of .spec, and got this error:
I tried to change the version os matplotlib on .spec requieremenets, but not solve...

Comment: How did you solve this error?